# Find the probability that none of these segments intersect inside the dodecagon

Tags: combinatorics

> A pair of vertices of a regular dodecagon is chosen at random and colored red. Other pairs of vertices in turn are chosen at random and colored orange, yellow, green, blue, and purple. The six sides or diagonals connecting vertices of the same color are then drawn. The probability that none of these segments intersect inside the dodecagon is $\dfrac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

**Official solution**

[image]

**Questions**

I think I am understanding the $\dfrac{12!}{(2!)^6*6!}$ part because we have like RRBBGGPPOO and we want to order those all but make sure that we don't count the same things. Thus since there are $12!$ total arrangement, we must divide by $(2!)^6$ in order to not overcount since we have $2$ of each color and we divide by $6!$ since there are 6! ways to permute each distinct set RRBBGGPPOO. The part where it starts to get confusing is the second paragraph. The definition of $f(k)$ makes sense but $f(0) = f(1) = 1$ is confusing ($f(0)$ doesn't exist but we can still use it?). Also, the sentence after that is where it doesn't make sense to me. Why must there be an even number on each side? And if so how does that whole set of equations follow?

Answer (score 1):

Good questions. I would first like to point out that there must be an even number of sides because we are pairing the vertices. This would not yield a whole number of pairs for an odd-number-sided figure. $f(0)$ is defined as 1 because there is technically only 1 way to connect 0 points - do nothing. The following equations describe a recursion.

**Picture a dodecagon with vertices labeled A1, A2, A3, ..., A12. Connect A1 with A4. You now have two separate portions, one with 2 vertices and the other with 8 vertices, to further separate. The solution calls this $f(1)f(4)$ because you have to put one distinct segment on the smaller side (with 2 vertices) and four distinct segments on the larger side (with 8 vertices). Now connect A1 with A6. You now have two separate portions with 4 and 6 vertices to "recut." You can see that the number of ways to do this is $f(2)f(3)$ (just halving the number of vertices). You continue to find $f(n)$ in terms of sums of products, making your portions smaller and smaller, until you have constructed all possible segments. One more thing: do not forget the trivial case of connecting A1 to A2, a side connection, which makes portions of size 0 and 10 vertices. This is where $f(0)f(5)$ comes from in the $f(6)$ calculation.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I don't get the recursion part where they say like $f(2) = f(0)f(1)+f(1)f(0)$.

Comment: Sorry if my solution was vague; I will now make it more detailed and see if it makes any sense.

Comment: The one thing I don't get now is the $i-1$ and $k-i$ thing. How are they getting that?

Comment: The solution uses $i$ as an index for each count. Think about it like this: when we connect the vertex $A_{1}$ to vertex $A_{2i},$ we divide the figure into smaller portions - one with $i - 1$ pairs of vertices and the other with $6 - i$ pairs of vertices - both of which need to be further divided. If we use the recursion and start on a smaller division, the $6 - i$ will then be $k - i,$ where k is the number of pairs of vertices to begin with. For $k = 6,$ the original problem, this is the same as the sum $f(0)f(5) + f(1)f(4) + f(2)f(3) + f(3)f(2) + f(4)f(1) + f(5)f(0).$